# Redirect different pages based on IPs, too many connections

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need redirect all traffic to apache website except some IP to courtesy page, I tried to put these lines at the bottom of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteRule .* /coming-soon.html [R=301,NC]
```

With my IP `1.2.3.4` the website works, other IP instead have `too many redirect` but into address bar appear `https://www.example.com/coming-soon.html` , where am i wrong?

Thanks

Comment: _"where am i wrong?"_ - for starters, in just telling us that you added this "at the bottom" of your existing .htaccess. We don't know what is happening _before_ this, so we can't possibly tell how it might affect this particular redirect. And why did you put it at the bottom in the first place? This sounds like a situation, where all your other redirects probably won't be relevant any more - so why is this not _first_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the message itself crystal clear? You implemented an endless redirection loop. The URL `/coming-soon.html` will *again* get redirected by your rule, since the IP address has not changed. You need a second condition to prevent that:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming-soon\.html$
RewriteRule .* /coming-soon.html [R=301,NC]
```

This is a variant with a few additional changes that probably do make sense:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming-soon\.html$
RewriteRule ^ /coming-soon.html [R=301,L]
```